# Issue using create-react-app + typescript + immutable.js

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, immutable.js

I noticed recently that create-react-app now supports typescript but ran into problems porting my existing codebase which uses `react-scripts-ts` where most of my classes derived from [`Record`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) can no-longer be constructed with errors of the format: `Cannot set on an immutable record.`  I found an old [Babel issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7644) which sounds similar but I could not find any documentation about how to configure Babel to avoid the issue.  How can I get this to work?

I use Immutable.js as described [here](https://medium.com/@lusbuab/immutable-js-records-in-typescript-90ef3e15a4f0), e.g.

```js
import { Record } from 'immutable'

interface PersonProps {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

const defaultPersonProps: PersonProps = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
}

class Person extends Record(defaultPersonProps) implements PersonProps {
  public readonly firstName!: string
  public readonly lastName!: string

  public constructor(values: PersonProps) {
    super(values)
  }
}
```

See [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6789)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-write my code to avoid the use of ! and implement `Readonly<PersonProps>` instead of `PersonProps` in order to get the type hints around immutability.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the appropriate way to solve this would be to add "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" the "loose: false" option to avoid assignment (see babel doc on assignment vs definition : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties#via-babelrc-recommended-).  It will instead use the Object.defineProperty.  Assignment is not possible with Immutable.Record.

Here is my basic example, started with create-react-app --typescrip, I ejected the create-react-app to quickly test this "loose: false" option and it worked (see babel section of package.json): https://github.com/kimulus/typescriptimmutablerecord

Answer (score 0):

without testing this, does refactoring your code to the following help?

```
import { Record } from 'immutable'

interface PersonProps {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

const personPropsRecord = Record({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
});

class Person extends personPropsRecord implements PersonProps {
  public readonly firstName!: string
  public readonly lastName!: string

  public constructor(values: PersonProps) {
    super(values)
  }
}
```